# sql group by for counting distinct users

Tags: sql, postgresql

In Postgres I have a `properties` table  with following columns: `item, user, property`. Each item is unique and belongs to a unique user. Each user can have multiple items. But properties are not uniques, i.e., the same property can be the same for many items. e.g.,

```
item, user, property
--------------------
item1 user1 property1
item1 user1 property2
item2 user1 property1
item2 user1 property3
item2 user1 property4
item3 user2 property2
item3 user2 property4
```

Now I want to calculate how many unique users have the given property in their items, i.e., in this case I need to get:

```
property1 1
property2 2
property3 1
property4 2
```

I can think of an SQL query for that like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), x.property
FROM (SELECT user, property
      FROM properties
      GROUP BY user, property) x
GROUP BY x.property;
```

Is there a better way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: count(distinct columnname)?

Comment: select property,count(distinct user) from properties group by property would result exactly your request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select count(distinct user), property
from properties
group by property
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ad8de/4)</kbd>**